# Grakn Error; trying to load schema for "phone calls" example

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I am trying to run the example grakn migration "phone_calls" (using python and JSON files).

Before reaching there, I need to load the schema, but I am having trouble with getting the schema loaded, as shown here:  https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/examples/phone-calls-schema

System:
-Mac OS 10.15
-grakn-core 1.8.3
-python 3.7.3

The grakn server is started. I checked and the 48555 TCP port is open, so I don't think there is any firewall issue. The schema file is in the same folder (phone_calls) as where the json data files is, for the next step. I am using a virtual environment. The error is below:

```
(project1_env) (base) tiffanytoor1@MacBook-Pro-2 onco % grakn server start
Storage is already running
Grakn Core Server is already running
(project1_env) (base) tiffanytoor1@MacBook-Pro-2 onco % grakn console --keyspace phone_calls --file phone_calls/schema.gql
Unable to create connection to Grakn instance at localhost:48555
Cause: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException
UNKNOWN: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1, use getErrors() for more: Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=5f59fd46): com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ConnectionInitException: [JanusGraph Session|control|connecting...] init query OPTIONS: error writing ). Please check server logs for the stack trace.
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind -- I found the solution, in case any one else runs into a similar problem. The server configuration file needs to be edited: point the data directory to your project data files (here: the phone_calls data files) & change the server IP address to your own.